# Multiple table select grouped query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

We need to grab the last and newest 20 entries from different tables. However, the GROUP BY statement skips records because we are working with LEFT JOIN on tables.

All these records are linked to unique persons in another table. We store these person's id's in an array for more queries later.

We have a few tables (in which all those person id's are stored) and we want to get them sorted and grouped.
The tables are like this:

```
SELECT lastRecord+personID FROM t1
SELECT lastRecord+personID FROM t2
SELECT lastRecord+personID FROM t3
SELECT lastRecord+personID FROM t4

WHERE t5.Essential_Column_Name = '1'

GROUP BY personID

ORDER BY 'all the latest entries' 
LIMIT 20
```

With that, the relevance of all the latest entries should be equal. 
We do have a timestamp column as well. Perhaps that might work better.

Any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: timestamp would probably be your best bet for ordering.. but were going to need more than this to give an appropriate answer

Comment: Try: SELECT TOP 20 ... ORDER BY timestamp desc

Comment: Sorry, we need to combine those tables and at the end of the query have the unique person id's.

Comment: @tkendrick20 MySQL doesn't support TOP.

Comment: You need to show your table definitions. The material following your statement "That tables are like this" doesn't make any sense, at least to me.

Comment: I think I put it better in this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089417/union-mysql-gives-weird-numbered-results

sorry for the confusion guys!

Comment: I got the answer through the right post here guys. Sorry for the confusions et all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089417/union-mysql-gives-weird-numbered-results

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for an answer on this; this is the right post, answer and update to this Q:
[UNION mysql gives weird numbered results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089417/union-mysql-gives-weird-numbered-results)

With thanks to all for the ideas and providing the paths to the right solution.