# UNION mysql gives weird numbered results

Tags: mysql

I am combining tables to get all their latest entries. The first query below works fine. When I add a third table to it the results get weird.

This one works:

```
(SELECT AL.alID, AL.al_date AS ts FROM AL)
UNION
(SELECT MRA.mraNR, MRA.mra_date FROM MRA)
ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 20
```

And gives result:

```
AL.alID | ts
14864 | 2014-08-01 23:43:08 
14865 | 2014-08-01 23:36:46 
2401  | 2014-08-01 18:07:06 
2401  | 2014-08-01 18:06:00
```

While, this query:

```
(SELECT AL.alID, AL.al_date AS ts FROM AL)
UNION
(SELECT MRA.mraNR, MRA.add_date FROM MRA)
UNION
(SELECT AMG.mraNR, AMG.lastupd FROM AMG GROUP BY AMG.mraNR)
ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 20
```

...gives this result, where the first nr doesn't make sense at all:

```
3134383634 | 2014-08-01 23:46:20 
3134383634 | 2014-08-01 23:43:08 
3134383635 | 2014-08-01 23:38:56 
3134383635 | 2014-08-01 23:36:46 
32343031   | 2014-08-01 18:07:06
```

My questions:

1. how can I solve this in the query?
2. how can I group the results so it won't show the doubles (AL.alID)

Comment: how does it not make sense at all? you've getting your timestamps sorted in descending order, as requested. union only hides duplicate rows if ALL of the fields in the row are identical. just because ONE field is the same as in other records is not a reason to suppress. and since your union is actually FOUR queries (3 sub queries and the parent union), the subqueries are completely unaware of any "dupes" they might be producing.

Comment: You're going to far for me already :-) I'd like to have the AL.alID grouped as in the first result set. In the second set the unique number is somehow gone. And, we'd like to group that nr as well. Wicked stuff :-)

Comment: @marc-b: Gordon Linoff gave a great solution below. Thanks for the insights you gave. I learned from you today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
SELECT alid, max(ts) as ts
FROM ((SELECT AL.alID, AL.al_date AS ts FROM AL)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT MRA.mraNR, MRA.add_date FROM MRA)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT AMG.mraNR, AMG.lastupd FROM AMG)
     ) t
GROUP BY alID
ORDER BY ts DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

It will return 20 distinct ids with the latest values in any of the three tables.

Comment: Gordon, you nailed it! How many times can I upvote this to get banned? Thanks so much!!!